# What are the common practices for resigning when under an Australian employment contract?

Tags: employment-agreement, australia

I have been offered an employment contract in Australia for three years on a temporary 457 visa. I am a United States citizen.

The contract is governed by an enterprise agreement worked out between a union and the institution (a University).

The contract states :

> I am pleased to offer you a full-time fixed term appointment to the
>   position of [omitted]...The appointment will be effective from 1
>   February 2016 and cease on 31 January 2019. This offer is subject to
>   the satisfactory completion of a probation period for 12 months.

Nowhere in the actual offer document, or in the enterprise agreement between the University and the union does it state procedures for resignation/termination. The only language about resignation/termination is related to severance pay.

**What is the standard procedure and caveats for quitting/resigning when in an employment contract in Australia?**

For instance, my offer also has the following :

> Although this appointment is with [a dept], the University reserves
>   the right to transfer you to another position, which may include
>   relocation, consistent with your contract of employment and within the
>   scope of your employment.

In general, in Australia, when an employee is in an enterprise type fixed term employment contract, can the employee leave at will with the proper notice?

For all the people voting to close, enterprise agreements and employment contracts are *very common in Australia, so this isn't a narrow question*.

In the US, an employment contract must have a clause which states what the penalties are for a breach, otherwise there are no penalties and no legal force to require an employee to remain in the contract.

**In response to the close votes**

- Enterprise employment agreements are very, very common in Australia
- Employment contracts are very, very common in Australia
  so this question *is not about a specific company, it is about employment, generally, **in Australia**.*

Comment: I think you will really need to talk to a lawyer, if you can one who specialises in Australian 457 Visa laws.  I'm Australian and I can't even begin to answer how the 457 Visa impacts on your contract and residency status.

Comment: @JaneS Temporary residents are afforded all the legal rights of normal residents, the Visa part isn't all that relevant. If you signed a 3 year employment contract, would you be allowed to resign prior to the contract end, giving the required notice of course?

Comment: In the context of a normal contract, yes you can _normally_ terminate the contract by giving the prerequisite notice period.  Note that you need to check for any financial penalties.  If they are not explicitly defined in your contract then I would say they would not apply.  Again, I'm not a lawyer and my industry may be different, so I really do suggest talking to a lawyer first.

Comment: You will need a lawyer to give you legal advice about your contract.  That is not something we can answer for you here.

Comment: @ReallyTiredOfThisGame, I'm not asking specifically about my contract, I'm asking about how employment contracts work *in general* in Australia, which is why my question, in bold, is worded the way that it is. Employment contracts are far more common in Australia as opposed to the US...

Comment: The second point is tat the role is a "mobile" grade you would have to talk the union to find out what mobile is defined as. In the uk for BT  it was mainland UK excluding offshore or ship based roles. For a university it would probably mean any of the sites the university has

Comment: So the community thinks that employment contract policy for **all of Australia** is company specific?

Comment: meta discussion here : http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3145/what-is-wrong-with-my-australian-employment-contract-question

Comment: While I was answering your meta question, I thought of this, which is the governing body for employment awards and conditions in Australia.  It may help give you some guidance.  http://www.fairwork.gov.au/

Comment: I'm not a lawyer but from my understanding/observation, the overriding legal principle is "restraint of trade" meaning they are typically powerless to stop you quitting on whatever notice you want, regardless of the contract, ref http://www.australiancompetitionlaw.org/law/rot.html This is probably why they haven't attempted to include restrictive clauses. The bigger issue for you might then be your visa status.